# Pandas: Get column dtype as string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dtype

Given a series and the (unique) dtype of a column, I would like the dtype information inside as a string.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'], data = [[1,2], [3,4]])
df.dtypes[0]
```

The output of code above

[image: Sample output of code above]

**Goal**: Extract the string `'int64'` from `df.dtypes[0]`, which is `dtype('int64')`.

Have not been successful in finding a solution online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert to string:

```
df.dtypes.astype(str)[0]
```

Or if you're really only interested in a single value, use the `name` attribute.

```
df.dtypes[0].name
```

Output: `'int64'`

For the whole Series:

```
>>> df.dtypes.astype(str)
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: we could also do `df.dtypes[0].name` too.